# Best way to create a search tab

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

Currently, I have a task in which I need to create tab that shows search results accordingly.

Like I have three segment buttons

[ A-J ]    [  K-S ]     [ T-Z ]

Click on any of the segment buttons should show the filtered result, I'm confused related to how is the short and best way to make logic.

Is there any internal function available to filter results?

I'm considering here the array of string through which I need to filter.

thanks in advance

Comment: i would recommend using Regex for this.

Answer (score 1):

This might be help you

```
var arr = ["Aadsdfgdfh","Baby","bab","Caz","Dav","Eaa","Mers","Nope","O","P"]
var expression = "^[A-Ja-j]{1}[a-z]*"   //change expression accordingly

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF matches %@", expression)
let results = arr.filter { predicate.evaluate(with: $0) };
print(results)
```

Comment: thanks for the response, can you explain little bit about the expression ""^[A-Ja-j]{1}[a-z]*""

Comment: "^[A-Ja-j]{1}" This match first character of every string in array and "[a-z]*" this match other rest part if string.

Comment: I'm getting an exception using the above. "'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching, reason: (Can't open pattern U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX (string test, pattern ^[A-Ja-c]{1}*, case 0, canon 0))'"

Comment: I get it we don't need Ja, can you tel me how I do the same for case insensitive ? like it search for both a and A. ?

Comment: `expression = "^[A-Ja-j]{1}[a-z]*"` Its already there @ParvBhasker